# make table rows not moving when fading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 4 rows and it will fade 2 couple rows continiously. My question is how to make it stable when fading?
My html that show table:

```
 <table id="myTbl">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr hidden>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr hidden>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
```

My js to active the animate function:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.fn.slide = function() {
   var self = this,
   kidsHidden = self.children().filter(':hidden'),
   kidsNotHidden = self.children().filter(':not(:hidden)');
   kidsHidden.fadeIn();
   kidsNotHidden.fadeOut();
};
$(function() {  
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#myTbl tbody').slide()
  }, 2000);
})
```

Like the rows won't move when it fades back to back.. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes and change the `opacity` property instead of using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. Define a class `hidden` whose elements will have `opacity: 0` and every other element will have `opacity: 1`. Then you can use the [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function to change the opacity:

```js
$.fn.slide = function() {
   var self = this,
   kidsHidden = self.children().filter('.hidden'),
   kidsNotHidden = self.children().filter(':not(.hidden)');
   kidsHidden.toggleClass('hidden');
   kidsNotHidden.toggleClass('hidden');
};
$(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
  $('#myTbl tbody').slide()
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
:not(.hidden) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <table id="myTbl">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hidden">
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
```

You can also use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout()` to repeat the transition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to make it loop continously and the slide in same row... I tried setInterval not working. Thanks again.

Comment: @TấnTrungTrương I have edited my answer. Now it should work as expected. You can view an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9eazhso/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not much clear what you mean by: "how to make it stable when fading?"
However, if you want to smoothly change `kidsHidden` elements to the `kidsNotHidden` by fading out and in. You could make something like:

```
$.fn.slide = function() {
   var self = this,
   kidsHidden = self.children().filter(':hidden'),
   kidsNotHidden = self.children().filter(':not(:hidden)');
   

   kidsNotHidden.fadeOut();
   // Put it after fadeOut and put the delay you like
    setTimeout(()=> {
      kidsHidden.fadeIn();
    }, 500)
};
$(function() {  
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#myTbl tbody').slide()
  }, 2000);
})
```

here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4r3vpja7/20/

Comment: one more thing, I want to make it show one row slide from 1-4 to 5-8 to ... loop continously, any idea? Thanks again

Comment: The most straightforward thing you can make is: 
 ` let time = 600;
   kidsHidden.toArray().forEach((el)=> {
    time += 400;
    setTimeout(()=> {
     $(el).fadeIn();
    }, time)
   })`

But I would definitely recommend to check out the Jquery documentation https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn
There must be a better way to handle these kinds of behaviours

Comment: could you check this for me [code](https://jsfiddle.net/2n8faxhz/) . seem it not like what I want.